# Show button for each iteration of foreach loop

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module

I have built a module using Joomla's subform XML. The XML in the subform is

```
    <fieldset name="topics" label="Topic">
       <field name="title" type="text" default="" label="Title" description="" filter="raw" />
       <field name="image" type="media" directory="" />
       <field name="description" type="editor" label="Content" description="" filter="safehtml" />
    </fieldset>
```

I need to show a button for each of the loops which acts as an anchor to the output. So it looks something similar to this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, fetch the topics in your **mod_xxxx.php**:

```
$topics = $params->get('topics');
$topics = gettype($topics) === 'string' ? json_decode($topics) : $topics;
```

Then, in your **default.php**, you can perform the iteration:

```
<?php // Create the triggers ?>
<?php foreach ($topics as $key => $topic) : ?>
    <a href="#topic-<?php echo $key; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">
        <?php echo $topic->title; ?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php // Create the anchors ?>
<?php foreach ($topics as $key => $topic) : ?>
    <article id="topic-<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <h3><?php echo $topic->title; ?></h3>
        <img src="<?php echo $topic->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $topic->title; ?>">
        <?php echo $topic->description; ?>
    </article>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```